# How does BERT word embedding preprocess work

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I'm trying to figure out what `BERT` preprocess does. I mean, how it is done. But I can't find a good explanation. I would appreciate, if somebody know, a link to a better and deeply explained solution.
If someone, by the other hand, wants to solve it here, I would be also extremly thankful!

My question is, how does `BERT` mathematically convert a string input into a vector of numbers with fixed size? Which are the logical steps that follows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BERT provides its own tokenizer. Because BERT is a pretrained model that expects input data in a specific format, following are required:

- A special token, `[SEP]`, to mark the end of a sentence, or the
  separation between two sentences
- A special token, `[CLS]`, at the
  beginning of our text. This token is used for classification tasks,
  but BERT expects it no matter what your application is.
- Tokens that conform with the fixed vocabulary used in BERT
- The Token IDs for the tokens, from BERT’s tokenizer
- Mask IDs to indicate which elements in the sequence are tokens and which are padding elements
- Segment IDs used to distinguish different sentences
- Positional Embeddings used to show token position within the sequence

.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer

# Load pre-trained model tokenizer (vocabulary)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# An example sentence 
text = "Sentence to embed"

# Add the special tokens.
marked_text = "[CLS] " + text + " [SEP]"

# Split the sentence into tokens.
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(marked_text)

# Map the token strings to their vocabulary indices.
indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)
```

Have a look at this excellent [tutorial](https://mccormickml.com/2019/05/14/BERT-word-embeddings-tutorial/) for more details.